# Is the dollar operator ($) supported in elm?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

In Haskell, you can use the `$` operator to clean up bits of code, removing the need for parens.

Does elm support this operator, or something like it?

I can define it myself but I was hoping that this was something built-in.

Here's how it works:

```
import Html
import List exposing (map, foldr)

datas = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]

{--}
($) : (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
($) a b = a b
infixr 0 $
--}

main =
  {-- replace all these parens
  Html.text (toString (foldr (++) "" (map fst datas)))
  --}
  Html.text $ toString $ foldr (++) "" $ map fst datas
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, we use `<|` instead of `$`. We borrowed it from F# along with the flipped version `|>` and `<<` for composition `.` and the flipped version `>>`.
Once these were introduced, people naturally gravitated towards a style dubbed 'pipelining', where you take some data and transform it in a couple of steps using the `|>` operator. These days this is a more common code pattern in Elm code than using `<|`.

For example:

```
update : (Float, Keys) -> Model -> Model
update (dt, keys) mario =
  mario
  |> gravity dt
  |> jump keys
  |> walk keys
  |> physics dt
```

(Taken from the [Mario example on the website](http://debug.elm-lang.org/edit/Mario.elm))

Comment: Nice. I had seen this in the docs but hadn't made the connection how you could clean stuff up with it in the same way.  I'd definitely want to use `|>` and read my code forwards than `$` and have to read my code backwards

Comment: also, this is called the "thrush" operator in clojure, but it's implemented an infix operator over curried functions instead of as a macro.